# Higher dimensional Cauchy interlacing theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues

If $A$ is a Hermitian matrix and $A_j$ the principal minor with the $j$ row and column deleted and $\phi_A(x)$ the characteristic polynomial. The Cauchy interlacing iheorem states that the roots of $\phi_A(x)$ and $\phi_{A_j}(x)$ interlace.
Let $\Phi_A(x_1,...,x_n)=\det (I_x-A)$ , $I_x=\mathrm{diag} \{ x_1,..x_n\}$ be the multi-variable characteristic polynomial. Then it is well known $\Phi_A(x)$ and $\Phi_{A_j}(x)$ are real stable, ie. along any positive ray $x_k(t)=a_k+tb_k$ with real $a_k,b_k$ and $b_k>0, k=1,...,n$, the one variable polynomial $\Phi_A(x(t)),\Phi_{A_j}(x(t))$ are real rooted. It is then natural to guess that in fact the roots of $\Phi_A(x(t))$ and $\Phi_{A_j}(x(t))$ interlace along any positive ray. I can prove this in special case when $A$ are adjacency matrices of trees and numerically check many cases in general but a complete proof is still lacking. Is this something well known ? I can't seem to find it. Maybe there is a simple proof just to transform any positive ray into a diagonal in the positive quadrant ?

Comment: Probably missing something, but doesn't $\Phi_A(x(t))=\det(B)\cdot\det(tI-C)$ and $\Phi_{A_j}(x(t)) = \det(B_j)\cdot(tI-C_j)$ where $C=B^{-1/2}(A-A')B^{1/2}$ (where $A'=\text{diag}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and $B=\text{diag}(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$)? In that case, the usual interlacing theorem should do the trick...